# How Do I fire a tag on DOM Ready in Google Tag Manager for every element of a certain class?

Tags: javascript, html, schema, google-tag-manager

I'm a librarian, and our library, like many, uses a system called LibGuides for its website. I've been working on injecting schema.org structured data into the site with JSON-LD using Google Tag Manager (which is about the only way to do it, given the limited customization).

I have pages on the site that display lists of multiple books, and I've written a tag and several variables that can describe each book with schema.org vocabulary. I've set up Tag Manager to fire this tag on DOM Ready whenever a book is displayed on the page. So far, so good. The tag works fine but for one problem--it will only fire once, for the first book, but will not fire again for subsequent books. So only one book shows up in the structured data regardless of how many books the page displays.

I've found plenty of instructions for firing a tag repeatedly when an element becomes visible in the viewport, but because this is about structured data instead of user interaction, I need the tag to fire on DOM Ready (I think).

I assume it's possible to do this with Javascript, but my knowledge of Javascript is unfortunately minimal.

Every book displayed is nested within a div element with the class "s-lg-book", and LibGuides assigns it a random id. At present, I have this Javascript set up as a variable in Tag Manager:

```
function bookGrab() {
  var nodelist = document.getElementsByClassName("s-lg-book");

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < nodelist.length; i++) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

The tag is set to trigger whenever this function returns "true." I naively thought it should fire for every instance of class="s-lg-book" on the page, but that obviously doesn't work.

An example of the kind of LibGuide page I'm talking about is here: https://nwosu.libguides.com/nursing/resources/books

**EDIT** A helpful commenter has asked for the tag itself. I didn't post it originally because I thought it might be too long, so here it is:

```
<script>
! function() {
    var e = document.createElement("script");
    e.type = "application/ld+json", e.innerHTML = JSON.stringify({
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "Book",
        additionalType: "Product",
        "@id": "{{Book URL}}#{{ISBN Number}}",
        url: "{{Book URL}}",
        name: "{{Book Title}}",
        author: {
            "@type": "Person",
            name: "{{Author Name}}"
        },
        workExample: {
            "@type": "Book",
            isbn: "{{ISBN Number}}",
            bookFormat: "https://schema.org/{{Book Format}}"
        },
        potentialAction: {
            "@type": "ReadAction",
            expectsAcceptanceOf: {
                "@type": "Offer",
                "@id": "{{Book URL}}#{{ISBN Number}}-offer"
            },
            target: {
                "@type": "EntryPoint",
                urlTemplate: "{{Book URL}}",
                actionPlatform: ["https://schema.org/DesktopWebPlatform", "https://schema.org/MobileWebPlatform"]
            }
        },
        datePublished: "{{Publication Date}}",
        description: "{{Book Description}}",
        thumbnailUrl: "{{Book Thumbnail}}",
        subjectOf: {
            "@type": "Article",
            "@id": "#col-nest"
        },
        offers: {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "@id": "{{Book URL}}#{{ISBN Number}}-offer",
            sku: "{{Call Number}}",
            offeredBy: {
                "@type": "Library",
                "@id": "https://www.nwosu.edu/library#page-content"
            },
            businessFunction: "http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#LeaseOut",
            price: "0.00",
            seller: {
                "@type": "Library",
                "@id": "https://www.nwosu.edu/library#page-content"
            },
            availableAtOrFrom: {
                "@type": "Library",
                "@id": "https://www.nwosu.edu/library#page-content"
            },
            itemOffered: {
                "@type": "Book",
                "@id": "{{Book URL}}#{{ISBN Number}}"
            }
        }
    }), document.head.appendChild(e)
}();
</script>
```

The tag of course has several variables in it set to grab elements from the individual book's description. I realize the variables might "break" if I get the tag to fire for every book, but I think (or hope) I know enough to fix that problem when it arises.

Answer (score 0):

Can u also share with us how your tag (which inject schema.org data for books) looks like?

1. Try to change your "bookGrab" JS function not to be a variable but to be a custom HTML tag (firing on DOM ready).
2. Then instead of "return true" line push single event to GTM for every book. Write single line like this:

`dataLayer.push({'event' : 'singleBook'});`

So finally bookGrab function should looks like this:

```
function bookGrab() {
var nodelist = document.getElementsByClassName("s-lg-book");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < nodelist.length; i++) {
dataLayer.push({'event' : 'singleBook'});
}
}
```

3. Then change your tag (the one who injects schema.org) settings (in advanced tag settings) to fire it once per event (not only once for a page).

[image: Google Tag Manager advanced tag settings]

4. And set firing rule for this tag to fire on event equals "singleBook" (or change event name to whatever you like [of course remember to change it name in bookGrab function also])

Of course there's a chance this will not work properly because i don't know how your schema.org tag exactly looks like.

Comment: I added the code of the book tag above. Taking your suggestion, it appears the tag still fires once, but I must still have something wrong because it's not firing multiple times. Per your suggestion, I made what was previously a variable into its own tag, and I made it trigger whenever the data layer variable "event" equaled "singleBook". I also set it to fire before the "Book" tag. It still captures only a single book.

Comment: First at all: I made mistake (sorry) in my code above. dataLayer line in bookGrab should looks like: `dataLayer.push({'event' : 'singleBook'});` (I forgot about 2 bracket).

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the bracket, but it still doesn't appear to be working correctly. It looks as if it's not firing at all. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: You mean that whole big JS tag doesn't firing at all now? That's strange. Can you also paste how exactly firing rules in that tag looks like?

Comment: Try to remove also exclamation mark from here: `! function() {...` and also round brackets from last line of your function: `();</script>` just to leave this code as a simple function declaration (because brackets at the end will try to call this function right after declaration [there's no need to do this]).